# Desktop Window Manager in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, dwm

Are there any new DWM APIs in Windows 7? If so, where can I find documentation on them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 7 API's are already documented on MSDN.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969499(VS.85).aspx

The following API's appear to be new:

- DwmSetIconicLivePreviewBitmap
- DwmInvalidateIconicBitmaps
- DwmSetIconicThumbnail

Answer (score 0):

There is some information on Windows 7 libraries and APIs at the [windows blog](http://windowsteamblog.com/blogs/developers/default.aspx).  That might lead you to what you're looking for.